Flutter animate using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode or prevent content jumping in android
Writing an app I need to go from a card with description of film to the video player and back. When I am at the card page I have system controls (top and bottom), when I go to the video player page, I go to fullscreen mode, so I need system controls to disappear.
Using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.manual, overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values) and SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky) provides the desired behavior but the content of my Scaffold is jumping (It is important that both my pages are Scaffolds and it is the same one on both of them). It looks bad for the end user, I need a way to prevent my content from jumping.
I've tried to animate the size's changes using MediaQuery but using SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode is a callback to the native android part and I have only a before and after values, no intermediate.
I've tried to use Scaffold parameters such as resizeToAvoidBottomInset, extendBodyBehindAppBar, extendBody, restorationId.
I've tried to count heights of top and bottom to calculate sizes and clip dots for my content, but MediaQuery told that top is 0 and bottom is 35 while the actual size delta is not 35 at all.
I've also tried to find a way to use something native and integrate that but I didn't found something appropriate.
If you know a way to animate that change or prevent the content jumping or if you have ideas and advices, I'd be very grateful to your answers and comments.
P. S. The application is cross-platform so ideally I need a cross-platform solution
Screenshots:


I've created an easy example where content is jumping:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  bool _systemControlsAreVisible = true;

  void _changeControlsVisibility(bool value) {
    if (value) {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
        SystemUiMode.manual,
        overlays: SystemUiOverlay.values,
      );
    } else {
      SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky);
    }
    setState(() => _systemControlsAreVisible = value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).height; // called to cause rebuild

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: buildBody(height),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => _changeControlsVisibility(!_systemControlsAreVisible),
        child: Icon(
          _systemControlsAreVisible ? Icons.visibility_off : Icons.visibility,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget buildBody(double height) {
    final mainBody = Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
          top: 20,
          left: 10,
          right: 20,
          child: Text(
            'Height = $height \nYou are in mode:',
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 100,
          bottom: 100,
          child: Text(
            '${_systemControlsAreVisible ? 'visible' : 'invisible'} system controls',
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
    if (_systemControlsAreVisible) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: mainBody,
      );
    }
    return mainBody;
  }
}

